# Get the file name that was created by mkstemp()

Tags: c, file, mkstemp

Is it possible to get the file name (and path) from a call to `mkstemp()`? And if "yes", how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [`mkstemp` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html):

> The last six characters of template must be "XXXXXX" and these are replaced with a string that makes the filename unique.  Since it will be modified, template must not be a string constant, but should be declared as a character array.

So you declare an array and pass it to the function, which will modify it, and then you have the filename in the array.

Comment: Right. I didn't think about that. Anyways, what if I pass a const?

Comment: @alexandernst If you pass a pointer ro a constant or read-only array (like a string literal) you will have undefined behavior.

Comment: One last question. Is there an (easy) way to generate templates for different OSes? `tmpnam` seems to do a good job there.

Comment: @alexandernst: you can build a directory name from `${TMPDIR:-/tmp}` in shell-speak; add some prefix related to your program, and then `.XXXXXX` at the end (so `/tmp/program.XXXXXX` might be OK).  If you're really worried, then use `mkdtemp()` to create a unique directory under `${TMPDIR:-/tmp}`, and then create a unique name within that temporary directory.  The cleanup is a bit harder; remember `atexit()`.

Answer (score 4):

The input string is modified to the file name.  Consequently, it cannot be a string literal.

POSIX says of [`mkstemp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkstemp.html):

> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> int mkstemp(char *template);
> ```
>
> The `mkstemp()` function shall replace the contents of the string pointed to by `template` by a unique pathname, and return a file descriptor for the file open for reading and writing. … The string in `template` should look like a pathname with six trailing 'X' s; `mkstemp()` replaces each 'X' with a character from the portable filename character set. …

The same page also describes `mkdtemp()` which can be used to create a temporary directory.